# Python create sorted list based on attribute

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need to create a list of dictionary values, sorted based on whether or not the value is empty, my attempt gets the desired output but has to iterate twice over the dictionary, I was wondering if there was a way to do this only iterating once? My actual dictionary contains like 50,000 values and just iterating once would save some time when doing it repeatedly

```
d = {'id1':[],
     'id2':[1],
     'id3':[1]}
l = [v for v in d.values() if v]+[v for v in d.values() if not v]
print (l)
```

this is my desired output:

```
[[1], [1], []]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort with respect to length:

```
l = sorted(d.values(), key=len, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [SortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) : Fast, pure-Python implementation of SortedList, SortedDict, and SortedSet types.

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList
d = {'id1':[],
     'id2':[1],
     'id3':[1]}

res=SortedList(d.values())
```